# Problem getting image to display using imshow (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I am new to opencv and am running the most basic line of code using opencv which is shown below. I have the jpg file in the proper directory and everything. I am using atom as my development environment. However, when I run the code on either the regular shell on windows or the anaconda command prompt shell the image I am trying to open using cv2.imshow('result', image) displays and then stops displaying for such a brief period of time that I cannot even see the image, almost like an instant flash, and then the command prompt goes to the next line indicating the code has been executed. From what I understand the code below should display the image continuously until I close the image or press some other key on my keyboard. No error messages have been displayed and I pip installed opencv properly. I am wondering if there is something I am not seeing that is causing this problem in either my code or something else I haven't tried. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('Image/test_image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('result',image)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: Try adding `print(image.shape)` immediately after loading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out your problem. It happens
while using the `cv2.waitkey()` method. "k" letter should be capital.
use as:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Also, try to use like this code below.
There is no problem with your configuration environment.

```
# importing cv2  
import cv2  
  
# Reading an image in default mode 
image = cv2.imread("lenna.jpg") 
  
# Using cv2.imshow() method  
# Displaying the image  
cv2.imshow('image', image) 
  
#waits for the user to press any key  
#(this is necessary to avoid Python kernel form crashing) 
cv2.waitKey(0)  
  
#closing all open windows  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask
If else give

Comment: Thank you I tried the suggested revision and it works perfectly thank you for the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: And once you have sufficient reputation, you can upvote the answer too. And maybe @Lahiru will upvote your question too.